# Why tikz complains when I use \NewDocumentEnvironment?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo}{b}{hello}{}
\AddToHook{env/foo/before}{\obeylines\obeyspaces}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (v) {hi};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{foo}
first
second
\end{foo}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (v) {hi};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm getting this weird message:

```
! Package tikz Error: A node must have a (possibly empty) label text.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.14 \node
           (v) {hi};
```

What's wrong?

Comment: you need to revert the catcodes after or use a different hook than /before so they are scoped

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks! If you post a full example, I will gladly accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noticed [by @David Carlisle's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661040/why-tikz-complains-when-i-use-newdocumentenvironment/661048#comment1644547_661040), your catcode jumbling will persist after `\end{foo}`... `texdoc lthooks` says

[image]

So you probably want to use `begin` hook:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo}{b}{hello}{}
\AddToHook{env/foo/begin}{\obeylines\obeyspaces}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (v) {hi};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{foo}
first
second
\end{foo}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (v) {hi};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]