# How to revert the effect of \obeylines and \obeyspaces for \input content?

Tags: catcodes

This is my file `a.tex`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[] (v) {hi};
\end{tikzpicture}
\endinput
```

This is `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo}{b}{
  % here I process the incoming #1
  % here I must revert the effect of \obeylines and \obeyspaces
  \input{a.tex}
}{}
\AddToHook{env/foo/begin}{\obeylines\obeyspaces}
\begin{document}
\begin{foo}
first
second
\end{foo}
\end{document}
```

When I compile `main.tex`, it fails with this:

```
! Package tikz Error: A node must have a (possibly empty) label text.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.3 \node[]
            (v0) {hi};
```

I suspect that I must revert the effect of `\obeylines` and `\obeyspaces` somehow inside `foo` environment. How?

Comment: You seem to be asking several questions that look like you have an 'X-Y' problem: you are asking lots of things that I think suggest your starting point is wrong. For example, it you are trying to read examples verbatim then 'do stuff', you should be looking at a solution for that from the start (e.g. using `listings`).

Comment: @JosephWright you are right, but this seems to be the last question for me (in this particular journey)

Comment: this is identical to your previous question. you should delete this and I'll answer there when I am at a computer or someone else will

Comment: The [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661040/why-tikz-complains-when-i-use-newdocumentenvironment) has already been answered, but this case is different (I believe)

Comment: @yegor256 reading your past dozen or so questions makes we wonder if maybe the `listing side text` option from tcolorbox could be useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal catcodes are 10 and 5.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo}{b}{
   #1
  % here I must revert the effect of \obeylines and \obeyspaces
  \catcode`\ =10 %
  \catcode`\^^M=5 %
  \input{a.tex}%
}{}
\AddToHook{env/foo/before}{\bgroup\obeylines\obeyspaces}
\AddToHook{env/foo/after}{\egroup}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (v) {hi};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{foo}
first
second
\end{foo}

aaa
bbb


\end{document}
```